# I would like to import the functions I have created (like Date.prototype.add, ...) into Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, nuxt3

I created a submodule called "date.js" and put all my prototype functions in it, including Date.prototype.add, Date.prototype.format, etc.
My functions are located in the file: modules/date/dist/index.js. So far, I had added the following to my package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "date": "file:modules/date"
}
```

And I imported it in my layout, using `import "date"`, it works perfectly in dev.
However, when I try to build and go to a page that uses a function I created, and then refresh the page, it says that the function does not exist.

I'm not sure if the problem is with the importation or if the file is in the right place.

I tried moving the file to different locations, such as 'composables,' 'utils,' and 'helpers.'
I also tried exporting it as `export default Date.`
I tried putting the function directly in the view, and it works very well, but I would need to duplicate the code everywhere, which is not ideal.

My project is Laravel for the backend and nuxt for the front:

```
| - app 
| - boostrap 
| - client ( nuxt app ) 
| - config 
| - database 
| - lang 
| - modules
| | - date 
|   | - src
|   | - dist
| - node_modules 
| - public 
| - routes 
| - server 
| - storage
```

My package.json for the main project :

```json
{
  "name": "station-donnees",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "lint": "npx prettier --write client/",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.16.19",
    "flowbite": "^1.7.0",
    "lint-staged": "^14.0.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.7.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.23",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "date": "file:modules/date"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "client/**/*.{vue,js,css,scss,ts}": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```

My nuxt config:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  srcDir: "client/",
  typescript: {
    strict: true,
  },
  app: {
    head: {
      title: process.env.npm_package_name || "",
      meta: [
        { charset: "utf-8" },
        { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content: process.env.npm_package_description || "",
        },
      ],
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: "fr",
      },
      link: [
        { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" },
      ],
    },
  },
  css: ["~/assets/css/main.scss"],
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
    },
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      webURL: process.env.WEB_URL || "http://localhost:3000",
      apiURL: process.env.API_URL || "http://localhost:8000",
    },
  },
});
```

my package.json of date modules is :

```json
{
  "name": "date",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "babel --extensions .ts --ignore src/*.test.ts ./src -d ./dist",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.22.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
  }
}
```

I created a page called bar

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>bar page</h1>
    <input type="text" v-model="date" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const date = ref("");
date.value = new Date().format("YYYY");
</script>
```

The bug only occurs when I refresh the browser on a page that uses the module, as if the module's loading is delayed or not happening.

Comment: Show us the code where you actually use that function

Comment: I think the issue is the name of your module, Date is a reserved name

Comment: oh thank you, I think you're right.
The problem is likely due to the architecture of my code, now I just need to import my module better I think.
I'll get back to you if that was indeed the issue and if I've fixed it.

Comment: `import '~~/../modules/date` may be useful

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your help. I'm really grateful to you. But I have a little question. I'm curious to know, how did you know that 'date' was a reserved word?

Comment: Well there is already a Date class in the browser, so i just guessing that it might cause issues to call your module Date